# Laravel SQL with where not in example and gettype with dynamic value

Tags: php, sql, laravel

There is one function for getting all the data from table with one where clause and one with not wherein clause. I am stuck when I am passing data dynamically but when I am hardcoding the data, it is showing me correct data.
**Hard-coded Example** :

```
public function getAllTickets($drawId, $existing)
{
    $login = [200263129,200263162,200263735,200263752];
    $data = $this->select('ticket')
                 ->where('wlf_draws_id', $wlfDrawId)
                 ->whereNotIn('login', $login)
                 ->get();
    return $data;
}
```

**Dynamic Example** :

```
public function getAllTickets($drawId, $existing)
{
    $login = [$existing];
    $data = $this->select('ticket')
                 ->where('wlf_draws_id', $wlfDrawId)
                 ->whereNotIn('login', $login)
                 ->get();
    return $data;
}
```

In variable **$existing** I am same data as **200263129,200263162,200263735,200263752**

But result is varying for both data and hard-coded example is showing me correct result.

Comment: are you passing array or string in dynamic programming function for $existing??

Comment: Can you add dd($existing); before the query and show us the output. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Please use this it may help you:

public function getAllTickets($drawId, $existing)
{
    $login = explode(',',$existing);
    $data = $this->select('ticket')
                 ->where('wlf_draws_id', $wlfDrawId)
                 ->whereNotIn('login', $login)
                 ->get();
    return $data;
}
```